# How to integrate a "donate" button into a website in India?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, google-checkout, android-pay, donations

We are developing a website for a charity trust in India. For this we need to add a "donate" button to the website for anyone who wants to donate to the charity through a payment gateway.

However, both Paypal and Google Wallet / Google Checkout restrict the use of the "donate" button in India (Google, rather than a donate button, provide a "support" button).

Are either of these payment gateways possible to integrate into a website in India? Or are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 7):

Indian merchants cannot use Donation buttons through PayPal. If you tried to pass `cmd=_donations` in your button code the buyer would get an error.

If you want to allow buyers to enter their own amount during the checkout process you can do that with a Buy Now button. Leave the `amount` field blank to allow that.

Comment: You can create a Buy Now button through your account with a drop-down menu. If you're using your own code you can use the "option_selectx" and "option_amountx" variables
Check out this page - https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/buynow_buttons/#id08A2G0920QN
At the "Sample Code for a Buy Now Button With Product Options With Prices" section

Comment: any other alternative payment gateway available for my requirement in india

Comment: With PayPal  you have access to Express Checkout and Payments Standard. Standard would be the Buy Now button I mentioned earlier and Express Checkout would require you to use a set of API calls to start and finish the payment. It doesn't have drop-down menus. You would need to capture that information on your site and then pass it to PayPal in the SetExpressCheckout and DoExpressCheckoutPayment API calls.

Comment: @PayPal_Patrick Are there any other countries besides India that cannot use the Donation buttons? Another question, why can they use the 'buy now' to pay them but not the 'donate'?

Comment: There are a lot of countries that can't use Donation buttons because of weird regulations. We don't have a full list of countries that can. If you check the Business section of the PayPal homepage you can find information on how you can receive payments.

Answer (score 7):

Update (Dec 1 2015):

> **CitrusPay does NOT support donations as of Apr 2014**

**Original Answer below**:

**Yes** we have few alternatives.

Here i have given one real time Example Payment gateway:

In India you can able to Integrate the **Donation Button** to your website for the `Charity Donations` through the [Citrus Pay](http://www.citruspay.com/) Payment Gateway.

Only thing you need to Contact `+91 87677 09900` customer care of Citrus Pay. They will guide you based on your requirement Mail.

Citrus is the Quick responding payment gateway, comparing other payment gateway for small transactions. See the [Citrus Customers](http://www.citruspay.com/consumers.html)

Also Citrus Providing the [Mobile Support](http://www.citruspay.com/mobile.html). You can integrate Mobile native apps.

`Note :` Once if you share your details. They will share their details like payments, Terms & Conditions, Support limitations & Integration tips and Guidance and Details.

Comment: CitrusPay does NOT support donations as of Apr 2014. This answer is invalid.

Comment: @Geotarget May be `CitrusPay does NOT support donations as of Apr 2014`. Since i have answered `july 2013`. there is No point to down vote. I dont know `Valid or Invalid` But its not accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a "buy now button" and place a "donate button" in place of "buy now button". Also there are other configurations which you can find in, [how to create donate button for indian website](http://www.codematrics.com/how-to-add-donate-button-on-indian-website/)

Hope This will help you.

Comment: Link in answer is dead.

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you use State Bank of India Collect OR create buy now button using paypal with price as blank (allows user to choose any amount) and then get code. Now replace a link from code https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif
to https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif